# How to properly trigger default action on a bootstrap dialog?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, modal-dialog

Most of the answers on SO are either about how to activate a modal dialog box or how the dismissal works.

However what I find lacking is how to trigger an action that the default button signifies.

For example,

[image]

the default action of this dialog is 'Save'.

Here is the html markup

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Dialog</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="btn-save" class="btn btn-primary btn-save">Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I call `$('#myModal).modal('show')`, the dialog box will appear.

If I click on the cross on upper right corner or the 'Close' button, the dialog box will be dismissed as expected.

However, when I press 'Save', nothing happens.

I used a round-about way to implement it:

It is written in coffeescript.

```
$('#myModal).on('click', _.bind(@_handleSave, @))
$('#myModal).modal('show')
```

Then inside `_handleSave`,

```
_handleSaveProfile: (data) ->

  return unless data.target.id is 'btn-save'
  # Do saving
  # ...
```

I don't think it is the right way because it intercepts every click event.

What is the proper to implement this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind the click event to the button instead of the modal :

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
$('#btn-save').on('click', _.bind(@_handleSave, @))
```